# Set-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline cmdlet deploys new pipeline with modified JSON tag values

Tags: powershell, azure-data-factory

I am using Powershell to deploy a pipeline to an Azure Data Factory V2. I am passing a file with the JSON of the pipeline to be deployed.

But, the new pipeline created in the target ADF has a slightly modified JSON compared to the one passed as input. The source type tag under Lookup Activity has the value 'CopySink' instead of  the value 'AzureSqlSink' specified in the input JSON file. Thus, Data Factory finds the deployed pipeline invalid.

The pipeline runs alright when I manually correct the tag values using the GUI though.

I have tried the below cmdlets. Both of them seem to have the same outcome.

```
Set-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName $DataFactoryResourceGroup -Name $svc.name -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -File "$currentPipelinePath" -Force      

New-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName $DataFactoryResourceGroup -Name $svc.name -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -File "$currentPipelinePath" -Force
```

Appreciate any help on this issue. My intention is to automate deployment of ADF pipelines using Powershell.

Comment: Have you tried with AzureRM libraries? They are the older version, but in many cases they work better for me.

Comment: I have to use the Az Module alone:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked when I executed the command from the Admin Powershell console after upgrading all Az modules to their latest versions.

Comment: Thanks for returning with your solution - you've probably solved a mystery for many people. You should be able to accept your own answer